# Extended Euclid’s Algorithm of GCD(19,7)

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find $7^{-1} \mod 19$, i.e. the inverse of 7. Everytime I ended up with `-8` but the book shows: GF(19) is $7^{-1} \mod 19 = 11$. I am not exaggerating if I say I've been trying for an hour to understand how 11 is the answer but I keep getting `-8`!! I use Extended Euclid’s Algorithm for solving this GCD(19,7), is that supposed to be right? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: -8=11 mod 19. Same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought Extended Euclid’s Algorithm brings you the unique inverse if both numbers are co-prime!

Comment: They are two representatives in the integers, but they are LITERALLY the same thing in the finite field. You have no right to treat them as not unique.

Comment: It *is* unique.  -8 and 11 and 30 and 49   and -37, etc.  Are all the exact same *single* unique thing.  There are exactly 19 things.  -8=11 is *one* of them.

Comment: List all the elements of $\mathbb Z_{19} $ and give them distinct labels.  Which label did you give $11 \mod 19$.  You had to give it either -8 or 11.    It doesn't actually matter which.  But whatever one you chose, that is the answer.  They are both the same thing $-8 \equiv 11 \mod 19$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $(7,19) = 1$. So you can use the [extended Euclidean  algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). In particular, you can find two integers $s,t$ such that $7s+19t = 1$. So $7s \equiv 1 \pmod {19}$.